# Vardhanti - Birth Anniversary or Death Anniversary or Both?

Tags: sanskrit, language

```
Vardhanti - Birth Anniversary or Death Anniversary or Both?
```

In Telugu Language, `Vardhanti` will be called/termed only for Death Anniversary
Recently I came to know that in Kannada - `Vardhanti` will be termed/called for only Birth Anniversary. This confuses me and feels there's a grave error among them.

What exactly `Vardhanti` means? Which is the correct meaning as per Sanskrit? Or For Both of the cases does the word Vardhanti will be called? which is the right term to be called?

Kindly clarify.

Comment: It means death anniversary. It is used in stead of Jayanti when referring to the birthdays (ie the day they assumed the physical body) of sanyasis. A sanyasi's true birthday is the day they take sanyasa deeksha for it is a true rebirth for them. Both words are sanskrit.

Comment: Vardhanthi means Death Anniversary. Birth Anniversary is called Jayanthi in Telugu.

Comment: @moonstar2001 you say for Sanyasis, Vardanthi and Jayanthi are same?

Comment: @AnilKumar ordinary person's jayanti = sanyasi's vardhanti.

Comment: @moonstar2001 what you said was, when normal people take up their **Sanyasi deeksha**, this deeksha is considered as rebirth and it is **Jayanti** for Sanyasi in them. So, Vardanthi of his former Human characteristics of him is Jayanti of Sanyasi (new form of him). **What about the date that Sanyasi takes Samadhi and leaves his Physical body?**

Comment: @AnilKumar and others. Turns out I was wrong. According to Sringeri muth, vardhanti is also used for birthday. One's completed years are jayanti and the following year is the vardhanti because vardhanam means growing. So if  jagadguru has  completed 60 years and is entering 61st year, it is His 60th jayanti and 61st vardhanti.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Yeah, **वर्धन** means **strengthening** as said by [Sanskrit](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0+&tinput=+vardhaanam&trans=Translate&direction=AU) dictionary. So if a Sanyasi takes Samadhi on Dec 19, 2015 and his age is 70 and what about the date Dec 19, 2016? will it be 71st Vardhanti and his birthday in next year 2016 would be 71st Jayanthi. Right? This [Telugu](http://www.andhrabharati.com/dictionary/) dictionary gives it as birthday too.

Comment: Dec19,2016 is his aradhana

Comment: I'm confused. Kindly clarify on usage of the word `Vardhanti`

Comment: Vardhanti is death anniversary, jayanthi is birth anniversary

Answer (score 2):

The following is in part a reproduction (translation) from Shringeri MahaSamsthanam's Telugu Panchangam (Saarvari, 2020-21; page 14):

"Vardhanti has its root from 'Vrudhu.. Vruddhau" (Sanskrit Dhatu words). It reflects the meaning of Vrudhi i.e. development, increase, or growing. On the birthday, Ayushya Homam is performed for 'Ayur Abhivruddhi'. Hence, the word Vardhanti is appropriate to use for birthday celebration. However, this word is being used by some in Andhra in another extreme sense. It is very inappropriate to use that way.

As someone commented in this forum - "Vardhanthi means Death Anniversary."  is very wrong. There is no more 'vruddhi' on death.

In conclusion, we should use Vardhanti for birthday celebration of someone living.

It's my observation that the word Jayanti is used for someone who passed away.

Answer (score 1):

Vardhanti is the start or continuance of growth. Hence applicable to. Living blokes and creatures only. Jayanti is victory so can be applied to.living and dead blokes

Comment: Vardhanti is  growth and applicable only to progress that is birth celebrations periodically  within lifevspan.. . Vardhanti can be used for death anniversary only if we have trikals jnaana and in cases where we know that concerned soul  soul has taken rebirth into a higher state of being

Comment: Now, Jayanti is that which gives prospect of Jaya or whichnis Vijaya Prada. For bharatiya that is applicable to all beginnings of action including birth . Because birth is the start of action for purusharthas. Anniversary of birth is to rededicate.oneself into purushartha goals  ie. Praying for Vijaya and new resolves.

Answer (score 1):

VARDHANTHI is associated with growth and promotion. Since we don't see divine souls leaving earth as their death and rather reaching the divine abode or convergence with the greater power, we call their death anniversaries as VARDHANTHI. This is not an inappropriate usage at all.

JAYANTHI means birth anniversary.

See:
https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=jayanti&dir=se
https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=vardhayati&dir=se

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Answers here must be backed-up with "authoritative sources/references". Kindly visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions).